# Comparing dates in an Excel sheet to a certain fixed date and printing a value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

I'm trying to compare dates from an excel sheet to a certain static date like 30 june of 2019, and if the date in the Excel sheet is before this print "Y" else print"N".

I'm very new at Pandas.

I have tried importing the file but no idea how to iterate through each row and how to compare dates to a static date

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df = pd.read_excel(r'Date compare.xlsx', sheet_name= 'Sheet1')
df{"Date"} = pd.to_date(df["Date"],format="%d%m%Y")
pd.to_date(df["End Date"],format="%m%d%Y")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your 'Date' column in Excel sheet is formatted as date, you can introduce new column FLAG by comparing Date column with Timestamp you need.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'Date compare.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

df["FLAG"] = pd.np.where(df["Date"] > pd.Timestamp("2019-06-30"), "Y", "N")
```

Comment: It's `np.where`, not `pd.np.where`

Comment: @CodeDifferent numpy is imported in pandas internally, so you can save some time referencing to np as pd.np without directly importing it.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that behavior. Sound like a hack to me but to each his own

Comment: This Worked Very Well And Easily, Thank you, kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure that the dates are recognized as `Timestamp` when reading the exel file with `parse_dates=True`. Then you can make comparisons converting from Timestamp to `datetime.date` through `.date()` and defining your threshold date with `datetime.date(2019, 6, 30)`. To do so you can define a function and use `apply` to the *Date* column:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Import data and define threshold date
df=pd.read_excel(r'Date compare.xlsx', parse_dates=True, sheet_name= 'Sheet1')
mydate = datetime.date(2019, 6, 30)

# Define function
def compare(date):
    if date.date() >= mydate:
        val = "N"
    else:
        val = "Y"
    return val

# Apply to all elements
df["check"] = df['Date'].apply(compare)
```